# I am getting a syntax error when trying to lock a label in ClearCase in a python script

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to execute a `cleartool lock` command.

Here is my code:

```
 def lock_label(lname):
        os.system('cleartool lock lbtype:' + lname'@vob:/cm_data/jupsw')
```

lname is my variable name

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you please provide that in your question. Also, from the looks of it, it looks like you got way too many spaces in your function

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the plus sign between your lname variable and the `'@vob...` part of your string:

```
 def lock_label(lname):
    os.system('cleartool lock lbtype:' + lname + '@vob:/cm_data/jupsw')
```

Each time you alternate between a literal string value and a variable name during string concatenation you have to add a plus sign which calls the methods that perform the string concatenation.